# How to divide all elements in an array by the same value?

Tags: arrays, c, function

Here's my code. I'm not getting the right output for some reason I can't figure out.
Here's the output I got:

```
Before:
5.500000 6.500000 7.750000 8.000000 9.600000 10.360000
After:
1.100000 0.260000 0.062000 0.012800 0.003072 0.000663
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void divby5(float arr[], int size)
{
for (size = 0; size < 6; size++)
    arr[size] /= 5;
}

int main()
{
    float array[] = {5.5, 6.5, 7.75, 8, 9.6, 10.36};
    int i;
    printf("Before:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%f ", array[i]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("After:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        divby5(array, 6);
        printf("%f ", array[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you probably want to move`divby5(array, 6);` *before* the `for`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your immediate issue:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    divby5(array, 6);
    printf("%f ", array[i]);
}
```

What's basically happening is you're dividing every element by 5, then printing the first element, then dividing every element by 5 again, then printing the second element, then dividing every element by 5 *again*, etc.

Pull the `divby5` call out of the loop:

```
divby5(array, 6);
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  printf( "%f ", array[i] );
```

**Edit**

And this is a problem:

```
void divby5(float arr[], int size)
{
  for (size = 0; size < 6; size++)
     arr[size] /= 5;
}
```

The `size` parameter is telling you how many elements are in the array - you're throwing that information away and assuming there will only ever be 6 elements.  Instead, you should write that as

```
void divby5(float arr[], int size)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    arr[i] /= 5;
}
```

That way, this function can be used for arrays of *any* size, not just 6.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `divby5(array, 6);` from the for loop and paste it before the for loop.
In this case it divides all the numbers by for `n` times.